# FontAwsome icon location not displaying correctly on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

i use FontAwsome icon to put it in a login form, so a user and password icon appear when user enter the sign in form.

the form work correctly with chrome: http://im85.gulfup.com/4Q9sj9.png

but icons appear likes this in firefox: http://im79.gulfup.com/WFKCvm.png

**html code:**

```
 <html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="login panel">
    <meta name="author" content="WhiteOne">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- icon location -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/icon.css" />
    <!-- Set Full Background -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/background.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="bg">
        <img src="login-image.jpg" alt="login screen background">
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 100px auto 0 auto;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">

                <span class="usericon">
                                 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
                </span>

                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                <span class="passwordicon">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </span>

                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**css code for icon: icon.css**

```
.usericon input{
    padding-left:25px;
}
.usericon:before{
    opacity:.8;
    height:11%;
    width:25px;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    content:"\f007";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}       
.passwordicon input{
    padding-left:25px;
}
.passwordicon:before{
    opacity:.8;
    height:11%;
    width:25px;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    content:"\f023";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

aslo when i try to change the css code using developer tools or even from the css file nothing changed in firefox, that somehow strange!
anyone know how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you writing your own CSS for FontAwesome instead of just using the FontAwesome CSS conventions? Like, `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>`?

Comment: Also you understand that Firefox isn't going to pay any attention to any `-webkit` CSS properties or property values, right?

Comment: @Pointy <i class="fa fa-user"></i> didn't show the icon correctly before username placeholder. i tried it before i go to this solution.

Comment: Well if I were you I'd use the conventional `<i>` tag, and then add CSS to affect its positioning.

Comment: [Here is an example.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/JHnbr)

Comment: i do it using FontAwesome css: icon.css is now: `.form-control {
    padding-left:25px;
}
.fa:before{
    opacity:.8;
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 280px;
 left: 523px;
   
}` it's work great on chrome but in firefox the user icon is far away from the username placeholder: http://im70.gulfup.com/UeuLEA.png

Comment: @Pointy can't we add a stylesheet for firefox only? like we do with IE ?

Comment: Did you see the example I linked? It works fine in both Firefox and Chrome, and it uses the FontAwesome "fa" CSS without any modification; all that the example does is position the icon.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work in my code: the user icon is outside the input box. can u please tell me how can i integrate it with my existing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea to break the FontAwesome encapsulation the way your rules do. You can position the conventional `<i>` elements and get the result you want:

```
<span class=usericon>
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  <input>
</span>
```

Simplified from yours, but the same idea. The CSS:

```
.usericon {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.usericon i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 10px;
}

.usericon input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 20px;
  width: 15em;
}
```

[Here's the CodePen for it.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/JHnbr) That looks fine to me in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: thank now it's working great :) but please can u explain to me what .usericon input {} and  .usericon { } do? since nothing happen when i change any value in these 2 blocks.

Comment: @WhiteOne The `.usericon` rules are for the surrounding `<span>` tag. I gave it some padding mostly to make it easier to see in the test; you can adjust that as you wish. The `position: relative` makes the `position: absolute` for the `<i>` be relative to that box. I also made it `display: inline-block` to make it easier to work with in a layout. The `.usericon input` rules are for the `<input>` element.

Comment: ok get it :) so when i close the span tag before the input tag there is no need to add .usericon input { } block since it will does nothing. thanks again :)